# Runtime Error 3061 Help (ms access)

Tags: sql, ms-access, runtime-error, recordset

I've been wracking my brain trying to find what is wrong with this query and I just don't see it. I'm trying to open a record set and I keep getting runtime error 3061: "Too few parameters: Expected 1."

Here's my code...

```
Dim ansRs As Recordset
Dim qRs As Recordset
Dim ansQuery As String
Dim qQuery As String
Dim i As Integer

qQuery = "Select * From TrainingQuizQuestions Where TrainingQuizID = (Select TrainingQuiz.TrainingQuizID From TrainingQuiz Where QuizName = Forms!MainMenu!txtVidName);"
ansQuery = "Select * From TrainingQuizQuestAns"
Set qRs = CurrentDb().OpenRecordset(qQuery)
Set ansRs = CurrentDb().OpenRecordset(ansQuery)
```

I'm getting the error from the line "Set qRs = CurrentDb().OpenRecordset(qQuery)". I copied and pasted that query into access and ran it and it returned exactly what I want to get in my record set, yet when I run it in VBA I get the error. Am I missing something really simple? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First ensured that your form is open, then put the form reference outside your quotes.

```
 qQuery = "Select * From TrainingQuizQuestions Where TrainingQuizID = " _
   & "(Select TrainingQuiz.TrainingQuizID From TrainingQuiz Where QuizName = '" _
   & Forms!MainMenu!txtVidName) & "';"
```

The form value is not available to a recordset used in VBA.

Comment: That did it. Thanks a lot. I honestly would have never thought of that because I have LITERALLY the exact same where clause elsewhere in a DLookUp and it works just fine.

Comment: Yep. It can be quite confusing.